# Date Format in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert a string representation of a date to a datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = "2021-09-22"
dt = datetime.strptime(dt, "%y/%m/%d")
```

but get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '"2021-09-22"' does not match format '%y/%m/%d'
```

Is my date format in the conversion wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `strptime` format is separated by slashes (`/`), whereas in the date string it's separated by dashes (`-`).
2. `%y` is for 2 digit dates, such as `01, 02, 03 ...`, you need `%Y` instead for 4 digit years, such as `2000, 2001, 2002 ...`.

Try:

```
dt = datetime.strptime(dt, '"%Y-%m-%d"')
```

Comment: Hmm still getting ` ValueError: time data ' 2021-09-22"' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'